# Python Programming: Classes

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

I have just started learning Python and wanted to gain a better understanding of classes. 
Here are two examples that are in my textbook, the first I understand pretty well, however, I do not understand the use of "self" and "other" in the second example.

Could someone break the code down for me in layman terms, step-by-step and explain to me what is happening? I want to fully grasp how to use the parameters in the class' methods. Would appreciate any help, I really want to get the hang of this! Thanks.

```
class Album(object):
    def __init__(self, name, player, year, tracks): 
        self.name = name
        self.player = player
        self.year = year
        self.tracks = tracks

    def num_years_ago(self, current_year):
        "Return the number of years since album was released"
        return current_year - self.year



from math import gcd

class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self, num, denom):
        g = gcd(num, denom)
        self.num = num//g
        self.denom = denom//g

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Fraction(self.num * other.denom + self.denom * other.num, 
                       self.denom * other.denom)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num == other.num and self.denom == other.denom
```

Comment: other is simply the other fraction. When you say `other.denom`, you are accessing the denominator of the other fraction. E.g. variables a and b have been initialised as the Fraction class and have been given a denominator and numerator. When you do `a + b`, I assume that the `__add__` function will be called for the Fraction a, and the `other` parameter will be Fraction b

Comment: @Krishi , thank you for this! Cleared some of my questions up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! I'm excited you're reaching out to get a better understanding of it rather than floating along like I did in the beginning, haha!

You can basically think of classes like a small robot. The robot has some specific characteristics like a face and world domination plans (attributes) and the robot can do stuff like world domination (functions).

If we think about your first class like a small robot:

```
class Album(object):
    def __init__(self, name, player, year, tracks): 
        self.name = name
        self.player = player
        self.year = year
        self.tracks = tracks

    def num_years_ago(self, current_year):
        "Return the number of years since album was released"
        return current_year - self.year
```

The name of our robot is `Album`. So Album has a sense of self, and it also knows its name, who made it ("player"), the year it was made, and some sick beats on some tracks. The robot can do some math and tell you how long ago it was made.

In Pythonic speak, this means you can "build" Album by initializing an Album object with `Album()`. However, Album needs to know stuff about himself! So you have to include some arguments in that constructor. That looks like `Album("Dirty Computer", "Janelle Monae", 2018, "Pynk")`. (You don't need to include "self" because Album already knows its a robot!)

To break down the constructor, since you've given Album some stuff to know about itself, it needs to really internalize that, so you set Album's attributes to the ones you told it. That's what the `self.name = name`, `self.player = player`, `self.year = year`, and `self.tracks = tracks` lines are for.

Now if I ask it "How long have you been on this earth, Album?", it may think "longer than humans can comprehend", but it will definitely answer with the `num_years_ago` function. To call this, since you have to have a robot to ask this question, it looks like `exampleRobot.num_years_ago(2019)`. The dot operator (`.`) is basically a way of indicating that the `num_years_ago` function is called from the robot.

In code, this may look like

```
cindy = Album("Dirty Computer", "Janelle Monae", 2018, "Pynk")
age = cindy.num_years_ago(2019)
print(age)
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to drop questions in the comments and I'll clarify!

Comment: This is such a great explanation! Really broke things down for me, and I like the whole robot analogy haha. One last thing I wanted to ask is, for the second class (Fraction), my textbook says that "these methods will be automatically used by the addition and equality operators."
How does that work? Because after the methods like  "add" and "eq" are made, how does Python pick up that Frac(x,y) + Frac(a,b) should be added?

Comment: Maybe [this blog post about modifying the __add__() function](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/modifying-add-method-of-python-class.html) can help!

Comment: Kind of the tl;dr of that article is that technically, `add()` is called on an object with another object as an argument (so if you have two integers `a` and `b`, it looks like `a.__add__(b)`). When you modify `__add__`, you're basically overriding the `+` operator so it can work with non-number types, so you'd call it like `fractionObject = fractionObject 1 + fractionObject2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__add__` and `__eq__` _ are operators. 
The idea is simply to manipulate your instance through classic python operators.

`__add__` makes you able to do `a + b` with a and b both instances of `Fraction`.
`__eq__` makes you able to compare two fractions like

```
a= Fraction(3,4)
b= Fraction(5,7)

if a==b:
  return "OMG it equal"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I understand the purpose of the add and eq methods, and how they are to be used, but my question is more to do with how they have been formed in this case. Like how would I know to use "self" and "other" where appropriate? What does "self" actually do when we use classes?

Comment: Variables defined in functions cannot be accessed outside it normally. Variables initialised with values in the __init__ function could therefore never be accessed. self allows the variables to be accessed inside other functions in that class.